# Add exec file to Xcode macOS project

Tags: xcode, macos, exec

I'm trying to add exec file with resources to my macOS project. I dragged those files to project, everything compiled successfully and I was enjoying my life. The problems started when I was trying to launch this exec from the app. It failed with error - `Can not locate Image / ExifTool.pm`. This error occurred because in project resources are organized with folders [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3bvq.jpg), but in compiled project all resources are in the same folder [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG37l.jpg). How can I fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to control where in your app bundle the resource will end up.

To that, do not include this in your `Copy Bundle Resources`, but instead create a dedicated `Copy Files` build phase. This will allow you to copy to specific location with your target's bundle.

However, you should be able find whatever you are after, regardless of where they are copied with the APIs in `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I want.